# Why isn't selectedIndex working in this code?

Tags: javascript, selectedindex

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>

   </head>
  <body>
     <select name="" id="dia">
        <script>
         var d = new Date();
         var selector = document.getElementById('dia');

         for(var i = 1; i < 32; i++){
             var toprint = "<option>"+i+"</option>";
             document.write(toprint);
             if(i==d.getDate()){  
                 selector.selectedIndex = i
             }
         }

         </script>
     </select>
        <select name="" id="mes"></select>
        <select name="" id="anyo"></select>

   </body>
</html>
```

The select element is filled by options as expected, but the index is not properly set. I've tried every component in separate, and I don't get why it isn't working.:

- `selector.selectedIndex` works when I use it in console
- `i` is obviously a valid number since it's iterating in the loop.
- The `Javascript console` doesn't show any error or exception. So I assume there are no typos.
- Placing an alert inside the `if`, it does work. So I assume the code is entering the `if` clause.
- I thought that maybe the index was being rewritten after every write, but I've tried placing `selectedIndex` outside the loop and it doesn't work either.

So... What am I missing?? I'm really out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your i goes from 1 to 31, but selectIndex starts at 0. So if the day is 15, you're trying to select index 15 which is item 16th actually and you haven't added it yet.

For example this code works:

```
  <select name="" id="dia">
    <script>
      var d = new Date();

      for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        var toprint = "<option>" + i + "</option>";
        document.write(toprint);
      }

      var selector = document.getElementById('dia');
      selector.selectedIndex = d.getDate() - 1
    </script>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="mes"></select>
  <select name="" id="anyo"></select>
```

Or, with minimum changes, your code can be rewritten as:

```
  <select name="" id="dia">
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      var selector = document.getElementById('dia');

      for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        var day = i + 1;
        var toprint = "<option>" + day + "</option>";
        document.write(toprint);
        if (day == d.getDate()) {
          selector.selectedIndex = i
        }
      }
    </script>
  </select>
  <select name="" id="mes"></select>
  <select name="" id="anyo"></select>
```

Please note that mixing JavaScript code with HTML is very bad practice and you should try to move away from this as you learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already tried placing the code outside the for loop and it still doesn't work. I checked again just in case, and the index is still in position 0.  I realice that this is bad practice, I would rather use the add() method of the select DOM element but I'm forced to use this by the requirements of a teacher (sigh).

Comment: Your updated code works. Why is it though? Is it because the changes aren't applied to the HTML until the end of the script or because the code needs to be outside of the select tag for it to affect the select element's properties?

Comment: None of those 2 actually. Your i goes from 1 to 31, but selectIndex starts at 0. So if the day is 15, you're trying to select index 15 which is item 16th actually and you haven't added it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because the option for the current `i` doesn't exist when you're setting it.

Set it after the loop, and subtract `1` so that you get the right zero based index.

```html
<select name="" id="dia">
   <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var selector = document.getElementById('dia');
    
    for(var i = 1;i<32;i++){
        var toprint = "<option>"+i+"</option>";
        document.write(toprint);
    }
    selector.selectedIndex = d.getDate() - 1;
    
    </script>
</select>
<select name="" id="mes"></select>
<select name="" id="anyo"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but why is the `if` statement even necessary?

```
<select name="" id="dia">
    <script>
        var d = new Date();
        var selector = document.getElementById('dia');

        for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
            var toprint = "<option>" + i + "</option>";
            document.write(toprint);
        }

        selector.selectedIndex = d.getDate();
    </script>
</select>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r6wstsn2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
document.getElementById("option-id").selected = "true";
```

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. And even if you did, you should be setting a boolean value instead of a string.